# Find matching asset (image) for category

Tags: assets, categories

What would be the best approach to have a list of categories (brands in my case.) and if an asset (image) exists that matches that brand name show that asset or instead show a placeholder image.

```
<ul>
{% for category in craft.categories.group('brands') %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">
            <img src="{{ .. }}" />
        </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: So with something along the lines of;

`{% for image in craft.assets.kind('brands') %}
     <li>
        <a href="{{ category.url }}">
            <img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" />
        </a>
    </li></li>
{% endfor %}`

But with an if statement there too, if it's exist use it, else a placeholder url for the src.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add the brand category field to the assets field set. This way you can add brands to images and use `.relatedTo` to find them.

```
<ul>
  {% for category in craft.categories.group( 'brands' ) %}
    // This will give you the first image that relates to the category, you could use .find() to get all images and then loop through them.
    {% set image = craft.assets.relatedTo( category ).first() %}

    <li>
      <a href="{{ category.url }}">
        {% if image|length %}
          <img src="{{ image.url }}" />
        {% else %}
          <img src="http://placehold.it/400x300" />
        {% endif %}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect. Got what I needed and learned something new. Thank you Luke!

Comment: @kitsune what if you'd just add an asset field "logo" to the categories? That makes it possible to use the more convenient syntax `myCategory.logo.first()` to get a category's brand logo. Makes more sense from the data entry aswell, add logo, address, etc. to the brand category.

Comment: I'd implement my way if there are many images related to a category but go with carlcs way if you only need a single image to be associated with a category.